# How to return new Object every time by calling same dict value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to set class definition for dictionary element that every time by getting `dict` element new object should appear.

**Example:**

```
types = {}
types[first_type] = FirstType()
types[second_type] = SecondType()
```

And by setting `types[first_type]` I have to get `new FirstType()`:

```python
some_var = new types[first_type] # this is illegal statement.
```

How can I achieve this in **Python**?

Comment: That would be rather surprising behaviour. You *could* implement a class that behaves that way, but any user of that class would need to be explicitly aware of such behaviour, or they may get weird side effects in their code. It's not expected that `foo = bar['baz']; foo.something()` behaves differently from `bar['baz'].something()`.

Comment: Can you provide more context and a minimal example of your class?

Comment: @deceze I will keep in mind that.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've got already what I was looking for. If you still need context I just need get new type every time dictionary items are being called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making them into "object generators" themselves.

```
types = {}
types[first_type] = FirstType
types[second_type] = SecondType
```

Then you can get a new object each time by calling that that point.

```
some_var = types[first_type]()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example with standard types:

```
>>> types = {"list": list, "int": int, "dict": dict}
>>> types["list"]()
[]
>>> types["int"]()
0
```